# store gdb call expr return value

Tags: c, gdb, red-black-tree

how to store return value of call *expr* in gdb? For example:

```
(gdb) call rbt_next(&some_global,0x0)
$2 = (rbt_node *) 0x7169ee00
```

rbt_next returns the pointer next node. However, when I try to do:

```
(gdb) set $w_sess = call rbt_next(&some_global,0x0)
Error: No symbol "call" in current context
```

I get the above error.

The reason why I want this is because I need to traverse a global rb tree to find a match. What I want to accomplish is this:-

```
while $w_sess = call rbt_next($some_global, $c_sess) != 0x0
    if $c_sess == $w_sess
        printf "Sess found in tree\n"
    else
        printf "Sess not found\n"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Leave out the word `call`.  The part after `set $foo =` is just an ordinary expression like you'd use with `print`.